# changing default view with master/detail application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

can you help me with this one? I'm creating an app and I'm using a master/detail application, then I added a new class called MenuViewController and I want it to be the initial view to load when my app starts. I was able to do it but my MasterViewController does not work any more, everytime i click an item in the table view it's suppose to show another view called DetailViewController but ever since I changed the default view it doesn't show the DetailViewController anymore

Here's a piece of code i've done

in the appdelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        MenuViewController *menuView = [[[MenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        self.window.rootViewController = menuView;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;

     }
```

and in my MenuViewController.m

```
//  Created by Jan Arman Capistrano on 2/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Jan Arman Capistrano. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

-(IBAction)nextView:(id)sender
{
    MasterViewController *masterViewc = [[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:masterViewc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `MasterViewController` is instantiated from a XIB. If so, check that the UITableView has its delegate and datasource bindings (propably the MasterViewController itself)

have you tried to set a breakPoint in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, to see if it's actually called ?

Comment: yup it has its delegate and datasource on the xib, what should i do?

Comment: Then It might be because the code in this `didSelectRow` implies there should be a containing `navigationController` you suppressed...

Comment: i have those in my didselectrow,